# Fastest way to whitelist list of words by another set keeping words order

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm, set

I have list of words like `words = ['a', 'spam', 'an', 'eggs', 'the', 'foo', 'and', 'bar']`.

And I want to exclude some words (stop-words) defined in another list or set `stop_words = ['a', 'an', 'the', 'and']`.

What is the fastest way to do that and also keeping the order of original list? I tried to use `set()` or even `SortedSet()`. But it still doesn't help, words are still different from original order.

```py
r1 = set(words) - set(stop_words)
r2 = SortedSet(words) - SortedSet(stop_words)
```

Tried iterating one by one, but not sure if it will be quick enough on big lists.

```py
r3 = [w for w in words if w not in stop_words]
```

Comment: Fastest way would probably be to build a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (prefix tree) and use that to check for your words. To preserve the order you would have to adjust the Trie to consider the order of words/letters I imagine.

Comment: Iterate over your input list in sequential order and discard words that you find in your stop-words Trie. Then you should be able to preserve the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing a bit of benchmark with a longer list of words from Shakespeare (length 202651 words) and a vectorized solution:

```
text = requests.get('https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/data/shakespeare.txt').text

words_list = text.lower().split()
words_array = np.array(words_list)
stop_words = ['a', 'an', 'the', 'and']
set_stopwords = set(stop_words)

def numpy_filter():
    """Taking a Numpy array and returning a filtered array"""
    return words_array[np.isin(words_array,stop_words,invert=True)]

def numpy_list_filter():
    """Taking a Numpy array and returning a filtered list"""
    return words_array[np.isin(words_array,stop_words,invert=True)].tolist()

def list_filter():
    """Iterating over a list filtering by elements included in a list"""
    return [w for w in words_list if w not in stop_words]

def list_set_filter():
    """Iterating over a list filtering by elements included in a set"""
    return [w for w in words_list if w not in set_stopwords]
```

Here are the results with my 2,5 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i7, in the order in which the functions were defined above:

```
12.6 ms ± 378 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

31.6 ms ± 1.27 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

24.1 ms ± 4.98 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

11.7 ms ± 265 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

The fastest option amongst the ones tried is indeed the one suggested by @a_guest. This remains true even if you make the list 100 times larger. As you can see, transforming the stop_words into a set brings a significant performance improvement. Numpy is also pretty fast, but if you need to convert it back into a list at the end, the overhead involved makes it the slowest method amongst the ones tried.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `set` for `stop_words` and then walk though the original list:

```
stop_words = set(stop_words)
result = [w for w in words if w not in stop_words]
```

Comment: This what I actually wrote in a question. But if there is any faster way to do that than just iteration? I know that having persistent variable with set of stop_words will be faster.

Comment: @wowkin2 This is O(N) so in terms of time complexity it's as fast as you can get.

Comment: @wowkin2 No way you can get around iterating every word and checking if it exists in the set, so the best you get is O(N).